# Factory function, how to generate random key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a function that creates objects, but I want to receive the key for that object by parameter. How do I set this key? When I put the parameter the function does not take and sets the name of that parameter as the key

[image]

My code:

```
createData = (image, text, id) => {
  return {
    id: {
      image,
      text,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Just do `return { [id]: /* ... */`

Answer (score 3):

Enclose `id` in square brackets:

```
createData = (image, text, id) => {
  return {
    [id]: {
      image,
      text,
    },
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Enclose the variable that you want to use as the property with square brackets, like so:

```
createData = (image, text, id) => {
  return {
    [id]: {
      image,
      text,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: I don't understand,  you mark this question as Duplicate, but also post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the bracket notation like:

```
createData = (image, text, id) => {
  return {
    [id]: {
      image,
      text,
    },
  };
};
```

:)